# How to implement List message for whatsapp using twillio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-studio

I am trying to implement message list with dynamic content for whatsapp. As of now i am using twilio studio for user initiated conversation.

So if user initiates the conversation then business can send any message/content without whatsapp approval process. Now the issue is i have appointment lists where user can choose the provider ID to book an appointment. Please check below screenshots:

[image]

Now the issue is if i can convert that message into List Message then it would be much user friendly. So how can we do that? Open to implement any twillio tool which can be incorporated with Twillio studio.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, Twilio only supports [templates](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/buttons) with **quick reply buttons** or **call to actions**. You could use these if you want to offer three or less appointment options.

[image: cta and quick reply]

I know this is not perfect and hopefully there will be more message types in the future.

Comment: Can we incorporate  quick reply buttons with twillio studio's "Send Message" or "Send and wait for reply" widget?

Comment: Yes, the trick is to create a [message template](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/tutorial/send-whatsapp-notification-messages-templates) with the options (body: "Your options are a ({1}), b ({2}) and c({3})", options: A,B,C) then use the text of the template (e.g. "Your options are a (hot), b (warm), c (cold)") in the studio flow.